# Can I travel from UK to Ireland without a parent?

Tags: uk, minors, irish-citizens

I am an Irish citizen, 16 years of age, and I’m in the UK.
Can I travel without a parent to Ireland?

Comment: who are you flying/sailing with?

Comment: With consent of your parents (this is just "unaccompanied minor", which is standard for air travels) or just traveling alone?

Comment: Are you in Great Britain or in Northern Ireland?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions